# NetBeans Panel design

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics, paintcomponent

I am doing a project using `JPanels` and `JFrames` where I am to create panel that says "Welcome to Target" along with the Target logo positioned underneath the message. The classes I have are Main, TargetLogoPanel, and TargetLogoUI.
I tried messing with the design functions that were implemented into Netbeans 7.1, but could't find a way to draw ovals that way, so this is the code I added in:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(((targetPanel.getWidth()) / 2) - 100,
            ((targetPanel.getHeight()) / 2) - 100, 200, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(((targetPanel.getWidth()) / 2) - 65,
            ((targetPanel.getHeight()) / 2) - 65, 130, 130);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(((targetPanel.getWidth()) / 2) - 30,
            ((targetPanel.getHeight()) / 2) - 30, 60, 60);

}
```

The logo is to be 200 pixels wide and stay center when the frame is resized.  However, just with what I  have added, the circle is not drawn when the program is ran.  In my main method I put `new TargetLogoUI().setVisible(true);`
What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: *"What exactly am I doing wrong here?"* - Not providing a runnable example, painting when an Image would do, not calling `super.paintComponent`, probably not providing size hints back to the layout manager, probably not using a layout manager...would  you like us to continue guessing?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The project requirements are to use the draw methods, so I cannot use an image here.
Where exactly do I call `super.paintComponent`?
This is only my second semester with Java programming, last semester we did a tiny bit of it, so I really don't know much about swing at all.

Comment: @DarthCthulhu `super.paintComponent` should be the first call made in your method.  The main reason for this, is it will clear the existing `Graphics` context and prepare it for painting...

Comment: Does your program show a frame at all? Can you post a complete program that we can compile and run as-is? This will help us help you in a much more timely manner. Be sure to include only as much as needed to illustrate your problem and no more.

Comment: @Code-Guru Well I'm completely re-doing it now.  But when I posted this all I had was what was above and the code that was auto-generated by NetBeans when I created the Panel.

Comment: Since you are learning Java, I strongly suggest that you avoid using the NetBeans GUI Builder and its auto-generated code. You will learn more, and have less code to deal with, if you write it by hand. When you become more comfortable with the Swing API, then you might look into using a GUI Builder.

Comment: @Code-Guru Yeah, I've noticed a lot of things wrong with the way my instructor tells us to do things when I come to this site for help. Thanks!

Comment: @DarthCthulhu Using the GUI Builder isn't *wrong* per se. I believe that you will learn more about how Java works by writing the code by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on google for a bullseye and came across [this example](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/examples/graphics/35Bullseye/25ex-bull.html). I provided the modified `JPanel` below.

I set the `rings = 3` and flipped red/white in `paintComponent()`

```
class Bullseye extends JPanel {
  static final int SIZE = 300; // initial window size
  int rings = 3; // Number of rings to draw in bullseye

  public Bullseye() {
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
  }

  public void setRings(int r) {
    rings = r;
    this.repaint(); // new value of rings - better repaint
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // x,y coordinate of top left corner for drawing circles
    int x = SIZE / 2;
    int y = SIZE / 2;

    for (int i = rings; i > 0; i--) {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
        g.setColor(Color.white);
      else
        g.setColor(Color.red);
      int radius = i * 100 / rings; // compute radius of this ring
      g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So would you recommend that I ditch the NetBeans design functionality completely and just draw the string and ovals with my own code?

Comment: Just draw it programmatically, there are mathematical functions that can draw an object fast and cleanly. The math you applied was very inefficient and convoluted.

Comment: @DarthCthulhu Netbeans is designed to provide the ability to layout components. It's not a paint program.  If you need to do custom painting (as is the case), you need to write the code yourself.  After you've created a custom component, you should be able to drag onto a Netbeans form, but I'd encourage you to try and hand code your layouts until you understand how they work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with the snippet you've provided.

- You're relying on hard (magic) numbers.  While there are times this would work, it's a dangerous practice that you should try and avoid
- You don't appear to be supplying any size hints back to the parent containers layout manager, this will generally mean that you component will ask the layout manager for a 0x0 space.
- You're not calling `super.paintComponent`, which is required to ensure that the component is painted properly.
- You're relying on information from an external resource to try and position the container.  This isn't the job of `paint`, that's the job of the layout manager.

These are just the things we can see from your snippet, there may be additional problems.

```
public class Target {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Target();
    }

    public Target() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            int radius = Math.min(width, height);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(
                    (int)((radius / 2) - (radius * 0.5)),
                    (int)((radius / 2) - (radius * 0.5)), 
                    (int)radius, 
                    (int)radius);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(
                    (int)((radius / 2) - (radius * 0.325)),
                    (int)((radius / 2) - (radius * 0.325)), 
                    (int)(radius * 0.65), 
                    (int)(radius * 0.65));
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(
                    (int)((radius / 2) - (radius * 0.15)),
                    (int)((radius / 2) - (radius * 0.15)), 
                    (int)(radius * 0.3), 
                    (int)(radius * 0.3));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a few things here I'm not familiar with, but I'll use what I can. Thanks!